# How to check if user is logged in before redirecting to login page using local storage and react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, local-storage

I'm using HOC for authenticated routing. I want to check if there is a logged in user in local storage before the redirecting to the login page, but when the app loads it first redirects and then checks in local storage.

#### App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route render={({ history }) => (
            <div className="App">
              <Navbar currUser={this.props.currUser} logout={this.props.logout} history={history}/>
              <Switch>
                <Auth 
                    exact path="/" 
                    component={HomePage} 
                    currUser={this.props.currUser} 
                    loadRecipes={this.props.loadRecipes} 
                    recipes={this.props.recipes} 
                />
                <Route
                    path="/login" 
                    render={(props) => (<LoginPage {...props} login={this.props.login} />)}
                />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          )} />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Auth = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const currUser = rest.currUser;
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render=
      {props =>
        currUser ?
          (<Component {...props}  {...rest} />) :
          (<Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: currUser }} />)
      } />
  )
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    currUser: state.login.currUser,
    recipes: state.recipe.recipes,
    recipe: state.recipe.recipe,
    user: state.user.userToDisplay,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  ...loginActions,
  ...recipeActions,
  ...userActions
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

#### LoginActions.js

```
export const login = (credentials) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const user = await UserService.login(credentials);
            dispatch({ type: 'SET_CURR_USER', user })
            return true;
        } catch (err) {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

#### UserService.js

```
async function login(credentials) {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/login`, credentials);
        StorageService.saveToLocal(USER_KEY, data);
        return data;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to make the app first check is there is logged in user and if not, redirect?

Thanks!

## Edit:

#### LoginReducer.js

```
const loginReducer = (state = {
    currUser: ''
}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_CURR_USER':
            return {
                ...state,
                currUser: action.user
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default loginReducer;
```

#### StorageService.js

```
export default {
    getFromLocal,
    saveToLocal,
    removeFromLocal
}
function getFromLocal(key) {
    const res = localStorage.getItem(key)
    return res ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) : null
}
function saveToLocal(key, value) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

function removeFromLocal(key) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
}
```

#### the log of current user in Auth:

- first (when app loads) - currUser: ''
- after login and redirecting to HomePage - currUser: {_id: "5cc15863d1a9f045fcbd6d85", name: "amanda"}

Comment: You need middleware like `redux-thunk` to get working premises in reducers.

Comment: I am using it, maybe not correctly.

export default createStore(
    combineReducers({
        login,
        recipe,
        user
    }),
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

Comment: Do you mind showing 1. your login reducer, 2. StorageService. Also, in `Auth` log the values of `currUser`. Your issue here may just be how your reducer is written

Comment: Sure, I edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: try this: in your reducer, modify the initial state to become: `state= {currUser : StorageService. getFromLocal(USER_KEY) || ''}`. The aim is to try getting the value from the localStorage first (if it's there)

Comment: Also, since currUser is going to be an object your `initialState` should be more like: `state = {currUser : StorageService. getFromLocal(USER_KEY) || {}}`. But your check in Auth could be more like: `currUser._id ? ....`

Comment: It works, thanks a lot!

I thought reducers are not allowed calling to service functions..

Comment: They are allowed. Normally, I would put `StorageService.saveToLocal(USER_KEY, data);` as `StorageService.saveToLocal(USER_KEY, action.user);` in the reducer instead. Remember though: when you log out (to reset `currUser` back to `{}`}.

Comment: Thanks a lot! (: